# Show vector mapped onto plane perpendicular to unit vector?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I am reading Gurtin book about Continuum Mechanics and Tensors, and I do not see directly that the vector $\mathbf u$ is mapped to the plane perpendicular to $\mathbf e$.

Only looking on the formula, I would say that $\mathbf u$ is on the plane.

> $$(1-\mathbf e \otimes\mathbf e)\mathbf u=\mathbf u-(\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf e)\mathbf e,$$ so that for any vector $\mathbf u$, the *tensor $1-\mathbf e \otimes\mathbf e$ maps each vector $\mathbf u$ to the projection $\mathbf u-(\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf e)\mathbf e$ of $\mathbf u$ onto the plane perpendicular to $\mathbf e$.* The tensors

How can you show that the vector $\mathbf u$ is mapped onto the plane that is perpendicular to $\mathbf e$?

Comment: Is $\bf{e}$ a unit vector?  If so :What does it mean to be perpendicular to $\bf{e}$?  We take the dot product and show it's $0$.  So, $(\bf{u} - (\bf{u}\cdot \bf{e})\bf{e}) \cdot e = \bf{u}\cdot \bf{e} - (\bf{u}\cdot\bf{e})(\bf{e} \cdot \bf{e}) = \bf{u}\cdot \bf{e} - (\bf{u}\cdot\bf{e}) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to phrase your question:

> Why is $\mathbf{u} - (\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{e})\mathbf{e}$ perpendicular to $\mathbf{e}$?

Checking that two vectors are perpendicular is equivalent to checking that their dot product is $0$, so this question is answered by the calculation:
  $$(\mathbf{u} - (\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{e})\mathbf{e})\cdot \mathbf{e} = \mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{e} - (\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{e})(\mathbf{e}\cdot \mathbf{e}).$$
You don't mention it explicitly, but I'm guessing $\mathbf{e}$ is a unit vector here, so $(\mathbf{e}\cdot \mathbf{e}) = 1$ and this dot product is indeed $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your assumption is right, **e** is the unit vector. Lol, I write in my question "I would say that u is on the plane, but this is not case here." So I thought too challenging, since **u** is on the plane.